# Do we have a publications tag? Do we need one?

Tags: discussion

"I have [a question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44402/167) about FAA handbooks", said Steve-V.  "I will ask it on Aviation.SE and surely there will be a tag for [publications](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publications) or [handbooks](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handbooks).

*And thus Steve looked, and lo! there was no tag to be found*

"But surely no," thought Steve, "We can't have been a site for over two years without a [handbooks](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handbooks) question!  Maybe I just missed it?"

*But he hadn't.*

**Had he?**

Comment: Could be useful but such questions probably have the regulations tag which you can search with.

Comment: We have very few questions about handbooks themselves, IMO. We have a lot that can be answered by looking in various handbooks, but I think we consider those as questions about topic X, not about the handbooks per se. I don't think we really need a tag for this, but you're always welcome to create one and see if people use it.

Comment: +1 simply because it's an excellently written question! :)